# Turn to multiple records

Tags: sql, oracle, frameworks, cube, cognos

I have records coming as below:

```
Item   | Color Code
Bag    | 1,2,3
```

How can I turn these record into:

```
Item   | Color Code
Bag    | 1
Bag    | 2
Bag    | 3
```

at SQL level without any intervention of new program.

I have problem to build a package and cube without this format of data

Comment: Is color code always 1,2,3? How many color codes are there? Are they always separated by comma?

Comment: Never stora data as comma separated values, it will only cause you lots of trouble. One row per item is the SQL way!

Comment: hi utsav and jarlh..
this is the source data from the vendor db.. i cant do any apart from finding solution.. T_T appreciate for the prompt reply and this is solve my bottleneck to build the cube.. 

there are around 100 + codes.... i will just use the cube technology on binding the color description with the purpose to reduce the load on the source db in stead of using the joins

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
with t1(Item,ColorCode) as
  (select 'Bag', '1,2,3'  from dual)
select Item,regexp_substr(ColorCode, '[^,]+', 1, level) result
from t1
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(ColorCode, '[^,]+')) + 1;
```

Comment: thanks u! it is working..
i applied the sql in cognos (SQL type = Pass through) and this is working.. but may i know if this will give extra load on the db performance? or how should i measure the impact?

Comment: If the data is stored in comma separated values, then you have to use regular expression to extract it. So this is as fast as you can retrieve it. To view performance, you can see the `explain plan` for it but you cannot reduce it further down. Also if the answer worked for you, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) it by clicking the tick symbol on left of the answer so it could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT t.Item,
        trim(regexp_substr(t.ColorCode, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) ColorCode
  FROM t,
   TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
   (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.ColorCode, ',')+1)
                AS sys.odciNumberList
                )
        ) lines
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9f57/2)**